# Stop debugging other projects

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010, wcf-client, visual-studio-debugging

It's really a silly question since I'm still newbie !

**Case :**
Solution contains:
 - A simple Discovery Service ( Hosted in Local IIS )
 - A simple Service ( WCF Hosted in Local IIS ) that announce its start-up
 - A simple Consumer ( WPF ) that discover service through the Discovery service

**Walk-through :**
 - starting the Discovery Service by right click the .svc file and View in browser ( Visual Studio starts a server and opens my discovery service )
 - starting the Service by right click the .svc file and View in browser ( Visual Studio starts a server and opens my service successfully after announcement )
 - starting my consumer program by right click its project and debug [ *Problem HERE* ]

**Problem :**
When starting my consumer program both services' servers shut down and again starts up !!!
This seams that when I debug the consumer it debugs whole the solution

**Notes :**
 - Solution start-up made to none of my projects ( I run them separately manually )
 - My consumer doesn't have any references to both services
 - My consumer has a shared reference with both services ( Utility Project )
 - [EDIT] WcfServiceHost when debugging is unchecked for both service projects

Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your service projects may be set to start the WcfServiceHost when debugging other projects in the same solution.  To disable this, go to each of your service projects in the Solution Explorer.

Right-click on the project name and select "Properties".

In the Properties window, you should see a tab labeled WCF Options.  Click on that.

Uncheck the box that says "Start WCF Service Host when debugging another project in the same solution."

Just make sure you start the services before you start your consumer (which you indicate you are doing in your walkthrough).

Comment: Both are unchecked initially I just forget to mention that

Comment: It's the consumer project problem or the solution problem, not the service related.